# facebook integration problem

Tags: facebook, blackberry, blackberry-simulator

one of my application i need facebook integration. 
please help me what the steps i follow. i have secret key app id and all stuff those facebook give before integration... please send me a sample code for help.  help me...

Comment: it really depends on what it is you're trying to do with the api

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Connect?

Comment: Mr dawnerd i am trying to do is after facebook log in user can use this app and can post some thing on wall... thts it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General documentation: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/

Here you will find good overall knowledge, and more importantly a list of available SDKs depending on which technologies you want to use.

Desktop Facebook Application:
- Apps on facebook: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas

Mobile Development:
- Android/iOS: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile
- Blackberry: http://us.blackberry.com/developers/started/facebook.jsp

Without having more details in terms of where you are blocking, what you are trying to do, using which set of technologies, it's hard to give a better answer.

Comment: thnks for replying .. Mr. chetane